# Cannot login to ssh using back in time gnome

Tags: gnome, backintime

I'm trying to setup a scheduled backup with back in time.

After entering my ssh data (host, port, username, path) and hit OK I get:

```
Password-less authentication for user@xxx.xxx.xxx failed. Look at 'man backintime' for further instructions
```

Even if I enter the password in SSH private key I get the same.

How can I enter my ssh password in back in time for gnome?

Answer (score 2):

From `man backintime`:

```
To  prepare  your user account for ssh-mode you have to add the user
to group 'fuse' by typing 'sudo adduser <USER> fuse' in terminal.  
To apply changes you have to logout and login again.

Next you have to create a password-less login to the remote host 
(for further information look at http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152).
Type  in terminal 'ssh-keygen -t rsa' hit enter for default path 
and enter a passphrase for the private key.

Finally type 'ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub <REMOTE_USER>@<HOST>'
and enter your password on remote host.
```